# Unable to install ruby gem ruby-jmeter

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jmeter, chef-infra

using chef to install jmeter. It fails at the point where it tries to install a gem **ruby-jmeter**

Tried to install the gem mannually

```
(1:91)# ./gem install ruby-jmeter
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-jmeter:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Further observation and seems that its dependent on another gem **nokogiri**

```
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.0.0.rc2
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags... yes
```

So tried installing nokogiri to see why its failing after all. So it complains about not having the correct version of libxml2

```
(1:105)# ./bin/gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required!
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

I tried to install the libxml2 libraries using yum and found out that its already installed

```
(1:111)# yum install libxml2
Loaded plugins: versionlock
Setting up Install Process
Package libxml2-2.7.6-20.el6_7.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

So what could really be the problem and how to resolve it.`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

So i did some more research and found out that the devel packages were missing, which are required to build the nokogiri gem.

So installed the devel packages for libxml2 & libxslt

```
(1:113)# yum install libxml2-devel
Loaded plugins: versionlock
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libxml2-devel.x86_64 0:2.7.6-20.el6_7.1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution


(1:115)# yum install libxslt-devel
Loaded plugins: versionlock
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libxslt-devel.x86_64 0:1.1.26-2.el6_3.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgcrypt-devel for package: libxslt-devel-1.1.26-2.el6_3.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libgcrypt-devel.x86_64 0:1.4.5-11.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgpg-error-devel for package: libgcrypt-devel-1.4.5-11.el6_4.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libgpg-error-devel.x86_64 0:1.7-4.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved
```

Once these two yum pakages were installed, the ruby-jmeter gem was installed sucessfully

```
(1:118)# ./bin/gem install ruby-jmeter
Fetching: ruby-jmeter-2.13.10.gem (100%)
Fetching: unf_ext-0.0.7.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Fetching: unf-0.1.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: domain_name-0.5.20160310.gem (100%)
Fetching: http-cookie-1.0.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: netrc-0.11.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed ruby-jmeter-2.13.10
Successfully installed unf_ext-0.0.7.2
Successfully installed unf-0.1.4
Successfully installed domain_name-0.5.20160310
Successfully installed http-cookie-1.0.2
Successfully installed netrc-0.11.0
6 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for ruby-jmeter-2.13.10...
Installing ri documentation for unf_ext-0.0.7.2...
Installing ri documentation for unf-0.1.4...
Installing ri documentation for domain_name-0.5.20160310...
Installing ri documentation for http-cookie-1.0.2...
Installing ri documentation for netrc-0.11.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for ruby-jmeter-2.13.10...
Installing RDoc documentation for unf_ext-0.0.7.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for unf-0.1.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for domain_name-0.5.20160310...
Installing RDoc documentation for http-cookie-1.0.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for netrc-0.11.0...
```

Comment: your answer should really be more "cheffy" though if you're trying to do it in chef:   `package [ "libxml2-devel", "libxslt-devel" ];  gem_package "ruby-jmeter"`

Comment: We are trying out immutable images, moving slowly away from managing things using a config management.

In true chef way, its a bit more tricky. Given the cookbook  (https://github.com/johnbellone/jmeter-cookbook) uses chef_gem to install the ruby jmeter, you have to get the dependencies before it. Even if you add the first step to install these pacakges, chef_gem is called as the first resource as it converges.

One simple way to get this done would be to use "include_now" in a wrapper cookbook which installs the dependent packages.